# Installing GoGui in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-13.04

I tried installing [GoGui](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoGui) using the instructions found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=749811)

I did not have Java installed already, so I did a fresh install and modified the code to:

```
sudo bash ./install.sh -p /usr/local -j /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

It didn't throw any errors.
But, I can not find GoGui under Applications->games.
Please help

Comment: If it does not throw up an error, I'm pretty sure it got installed correctly. Did you try to `locate` the binary from your teminal?

Comment: Got it! Downloaded GoGui again from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gogui/files/latest/download?source=files) and tried installing it again.. And it worked!!

Comment: I tried installing and I got the error:

> install: cannot stat 'lib/*.jar': No such file or directory

> install: cannot stat 'doc/manual/html/*.html': No such file or directory

> install: cannot stat 'doc/manual/man/*.1': No such file or directory

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: @OfekGila I got the same errors, have you fixed it?

Comment: Finally I found the correct file to download https://sourceforge.net/projects/gogui/files/gogui/1.4.9/gogui-1.4.9.zip/download